# Hide Container If Clicked on Background Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide the popup if the background is clicked, but NOT the div.
Basically, when the user clicks the background it will hide the div; yet, if the user clicks the actual div it will still hide it. I would only like the div to be hidden on the clicking of the background.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="linkinputholder">
    <div id="linkinputbox">
        Title
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="displaylinkinput()" type="button"> Display </button>
```

CSS

```
#linkinputholder {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#linkinputbox {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS/Jquery

```
function displaylinkinput() {
    document.getElementById('linkinputholder').style.display = "block";
}

    $('#linkinputholder').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('linkinputholder').style.display = "none";
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by background you mean your linkinputholder div, which is 100% wide by 100% tall. Your jquery code was missing the call to displaylinkinput, so i added a click event handler to call it. When you click on the linkinputbox div, the click event passes down through to linkinputholder. To prevent this just stop the event propagation.

```
$('#linkinputbox').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
```

I have created a JSFIDDLE for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/oLgex1pq/

Here is the corrected javascript:

```
function displaylinkinput() {
    $('#linkinputholder').show();
}

$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        displaylinkinput();
    });

    $('#linkinputholder').click(function () {
        $('#linkinputholder').hide();
    });

    $('#linkinputbox').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** 
Check if div is target

```
$('#linkinputholder').click(function(event) {
    if (jQuery(event.target).is('.linkinputholder')) return;
    document.getElementById('linkinputholder').style.display = "none";
});
```